# how to simplify the following expression: $-(4i)^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

How to simplify the following term

$$-(4i)^3$$

I have tried solving it the following way: taking the square root of $-16$ to the third power and taking the negative of that. I am getting an answer of $-2i$ multiplied by the square root of $12$.

Comment: Use the fact that $i^2 = -1$ and it is simple.

Comment: This isn't linear algebra is it?

Comment: Good retag, Mr. Good Eats.

Comment: As an aid to you, it’s not an equation unless it has an “$=$” sign. Properly, $-(4i)^3$ is an *expression*.

Answer (score 8):

Like so.

$$-(4i)^3 = - 64 i^3 = -64(i^2)i = 64 i.$$

Answer (score 2):

The expression $-(4i)^3$ means:
$$(-1)\cdot 4^3\cdot i^3=(-1)\cdot 64\cdot (-i)=64 i$$